# Xcode Not running program

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a problem with Xcode not showing program after a successful build. Searched for some answers online and I was advised to update and I did. But the problem is still there.

Here is the code I was running.

```
//  Dog to Human age calculator


#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int calcDogAge (int dogAge)
{
     return dogAge*7;
    
}

double calcDogAge (double dogAge)
{
     return 16*log(dogAge)+31;
}

int main()

{
    int dogsAge;
    
    cin >> dogsAge;
    cout << calcDogAge(dogsAge);
    cout << calcDogAge(static_cast<double>(dogsAge));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "not showing program", by this do you mean Xcode doesn't launch the compiled app?

Comment: Could it be that you accidentally switch the output to Debugger Output? If you can see it displayed somewhere when you're running the app, switch it to All Output

Comment: Also, your app doesn't give any output before you input the number, so just type the age in the window that pops up, and it should return the calculation result

Comment: The output is on all output, my problem is that the program runs as it should when I use an online compiler.

Comment: Thank you very much, after giving an input that's when I saw that the program has been executed, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the console is closed imediately, please consider using `cin.get()`

```
//  Dog to Human age calculator


#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int calcDogAge (int dogAge)
{
     return dogAge*7;
    
}

double calcDogAge (double dogAge)
{
     return 16*log(dogAge)+31;
}

int main()

{
    int dogsAge;
    
    cin >> dogsAge;
    cout << calcDogAge(dogsAge);
    cout << calcDogAge(static_cast<double>(dogsAge));
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```